# Compute big number of Binomial in Hypergeometric Distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

I am solving a Hypergeometric Distribution problem. I am able to use the formula but I get error when I compute for answer. Below is the problem:

From a batch of 104000 resistors 2500 have values outside of the range of tolerance. A random sample of 100 resistors is drawn from the batch. Determine the probability p that exactly 2 of the resistors from the sample have values outside of the range of tolerance.

The equation for this problem should be:

$$P(2)=\frac{\binom{2500}{2}\cdot \binom{101500}{98}}{\binom{104000}{100}}$$

I get error when I compute these numbers for the answer. I think these numbers are big for binomial computation. Therefore, may I know how can I compute these big numbers in binomial?

Answer (score 1):

As a thumb rule, if the population size is more than $20$ times the sample size, we can use the binomial approximation to the hypergeometric distribution.

So we can safely compute the value using the binomial distribution, with $p = \dfrac{25}{1040}$, and compute $\binom{100}{2}p^2(1-p)^{98} \approx 0.2635$

To four dp, the exact computation gives $\approx 0.2636$
the difference is nothing to sweat about !

**PS:**
Re difficulty in computing the exact value using the hypergeometric distribution, it would depend on the resources you have. I had no difficulty doing it at [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5B%282500pick2%29%28101500pick98%29%5D%2F%28104000pick100%29)

Answer (score 0):

I see no difficulty in cumputing it. With pari gp I obtain
$$
P(2)=0.26362314648599139309164924422580095669,
$$
or as a fraction, $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a$ equal to
$$
13603055569434811645151390329539196032134978955422860907149089189132191400685436315678462904487419255267450183071136985063571810401581549457198321629539521820259169959315812759643478210053380689731864253507849882677108263844606988994955347863300975759646639172202188608522161492738568676758352070903507710151993200575251712372516956175211562500
$$
and $b$ equal to
$$
51600383922121425478989083369925338789596771911067356865204071690727490446424961726858965739059294623760055576253047909473975164805588392132773640286106837033534299201564630241966629015157296274974053278595485579540454056023131341122240745117606629160750715496959443210142222652559805251241516915311925061775189196858411973304774024325912063360
$$